# How to Fetch a file placed in a container that can be logged-in from azure vm via "dsh"?

Tags: linux, azure, ssh, virtual-machine, docker-machine

My requirement is below:

1) Login to Linux jump server from Windows local host 
2) From Linux Server SSH to Azure VM machine
3) From Azure VM node - dsh - to a linux card
4) Get the file from this linux card back all the way to Windows local host

Is this possible ?

I've tried paramiko/subprocess etc to perform SSH till Azure VM
but then I have to do dsh to a linux card n fetch file from there.
How to do that, any leads ?

Answer (score 0):

It seems you jump twice with SSH and get into the destination Linux machine, then you want to copy the file here to your original Windows machine. For this purpose, I only have two possible ways.

One is that copy the file directly to your Windows machine. But in this way, your Windows machine needs to be accessible from the Internet with port 22 and the destination Linux machine also needs to be able to access the Internet.

The other one is that you need to copy the file multiple times to each machine you SSH to. Finally, copy the file from the Linux jump server to your Windows machine.